# Testing divisibility by multiple numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, is there a way to test if a number is divisible by multiple numbers without writing out the modulo operation for each factor?

More specifically, is there a better way to write this code instead of typing i % n == 0 ninety times?

```
if i % 11 == 0 and i % 12 == 0 and i % 13 == 0 ... and i % 100 == 0:
    print(i)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use`all()`and a Generator Expression:

```
if all(i % n == 0 for n in range(11, 101)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Wow, we ended up with the exact same code character-for-character with a 10 second difference. I guess that really does show that part of "The Zen of Python": "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: and yet... I wonder if it would be faster to take the product of all of the numbers and check if the original number is divisible by *that*, since it has to be to be divisible by each of its factors, no?

Comment: no.  if it is divisible by the product then it is divisible by each of the factors, but the reverse is not necessarily true, unless you're only checking prime factors.

Answer (score 4):

```
if all(i % n == 0 for n in reversed(xrange(11, 101))):
    print(i)
```

Only a slightly modified version of the duplicate answers already given: `xrange` returns an object that generates the numbers in the range on demand (slightly faster than `range` and more memory efficient).  If performance is important here, which it often is for mathematical code snippets like this bit, the reverse iterator will check the bigger numbers first.  This is more likely to kick you out of the `all()` function sooner.

Comment: Good advice for people using 2.x, but OP is using Python 3. No `xrange`. `range` now does what `xrange` did in 2.x. The reversal is a good idea either way, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
if all(i % n == 0 for n in range(11, 101)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

(**Note:** This is of mathematical interest but the previous answers are better in practice.)

You could compute the least common multiple of all the divisors and see if the number is divisible by that. (Just taking the product doesn't work; consider N=16 with divisors 4 and 8.)

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was:

```
if all(i % n == 0 for n in range(11, 101)):
    print(i)
```

which, it should be mentioned as clarification, only works with the built-in all function. I use Spyder, which by default uses the all from numpy.core.fromnumeric, and the above answer will not work in that case. Then use the following:

```
import __builtin__

if __builtin__.all(i % n == 0 for n in range(11, 101)):
    print(i)
```